# Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I would like to know how you upgrade PHP in Xampp for Windows? I tried to download the latest PHP version from the main PHP site but when I check (phpinfo) I still get that the previous version is still in use.

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480590/upgrade-php-on-xampp-1-8-3-windows-7-installation) post. It works to me.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Take a backup of your htdocs and data folder (subfolder of MySQL folder), reinstall upgraded version and replace those folders.

**Note:**
In case you have changed config files like *PHP (php.ini), Apache (httpd.conf)* or any other, please take back up of those files as well and replace them with newly installed version.

Comment: I renamed my current XAMPP at C:\XAMPP to C:\XAMPP ORIG so that I could install the newest version of XAMPP at C:\XAMPP but still have my app's data and original version in case something went.  I was scared after I installed the newest XAMPP and saw that it "overwrote" my XAMPP ORIG - on my C: drive, there was only C:\XAMPP - but relieved when my htdocs and mysql\data was in the new, updated version of XAMPP.

Comment: I always used to do like this, but some databases in the backup data folder crashed when they are placed in the newly installed xampp folder. So, I'm always searching to upgrade PHP without apache upgrade.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces are you a xampp user? I thought it was perfectly clear for anyone who uses xampp... Still, my upvote goes to Dharmang, he answered earlier and with more precision, what if I want to stick with the same versions of Apache and MySql and just update PHP? This lazy (but clear) answer doesn't cover that

Comment: But sometimes newer verison of php is not bundled immediately in xampp, so this cannot be a general solution

Comment: Beware that this answer only describes saving the web and MySQL data. It does not include configuration changes to PHP (php.ini) Apache (httpd.conf and others) etc.

Comment: This is upgrading Xampp, not upgrading PHP with the same Xampp.

Comment: To me this approach is completely a fail. All data placed in the new installation are not usable anymore, even if I only installed the same instance of xampp.

Answer (score 74):

Simplest method to upgrade `PHP` in `XAMPP`:

1. Download latest portable version of `XAMPP`.
2. Extract the archive(not where `XAMPP` already installed).
3. Copy the `PHP` folder from the extracted archive.
4. Keep back up of `PHP` folder which is in installed `XAMPP` directory. You can backup it like changing the `PHP` folder name to `PHP-old` or
   like `PHP-version-number`
5. Paste the `PHP` folder which you copied from the extracted archive.
6. Replace the `php.ini` file with your backup folder `php.ini` file in case you have changed the default settings earlier.
7. That's all, start/restart the `server`.

Comment: I can't find the XAMPP zip archive, it seems there is only an exe installer.

Comment: @dlofrodloh Here you can find all XAMPP https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/ files.

Comment: Did not work for me. Trying to go from v.5.2.2 to v.5.6.

Comment: @Eir The above procedure is correct, may be you are not doing it in proper way. Try again, if still not work than copy your `htdocs` folder,  paste it somewhere else, also backup the files that were changed in the previous installation for e.g. `httpd-vhosts.conf`, `php.ini` or php extensions, now uninstall `XAMPP` and install latest version. Make changes into new installation if required, hope this will work for you.

Comment: Update in 2018: I tried updating 7.0.27 to 7.2.7 and worked like charm. The biggest advantage over reinstalling whole xampp is keeping all the settings up (except for that php.ini). Thanks for that

Comment: It might be simplest method to download the latest XAMPP version, but if you need MySQL and not MariaDB its a big mess to get MySQL working again. XAMPP replaced MySQL with MariaDB for weird reasons.

Comment: @sba The question for upgrading PHP so nothing to do with MySQL but anyone worry about it, here is the [solution](https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece). The solution is for replacing MariaDB with MySQL so if you already have MySQL then you to make changes accordingly.

Comment: @VikasKhunteta i know this is purely about upgrading PHP but in real world you often need to take DB into consideration too and it might be a rude awakening seeing your stuff not working anymore. I tried a couple of solution, non worked for me so far, so i moved away from complete environments like XAMPP.

Comment: This worked for me for PHP  7.2.5 to 7.3.0... great solution, thank you. Certainly a good idea to backup your sites & DB before you do anything.

Comment: Actually, my PhpMyAdmin started to play up a little, so I also stopped my MySQL server, copied the files out of the portable xampp\phpMyAdmin folder into my local installation and restarted the service. All is working properly now.

Comment: @AdheneManx I had the same issue and your PHPMyAdmin suggestion worked great. I also want to point out that I have my PHP version installed as x86, therefore the x64 versions won't work. It is needed to download the correct portable version of Xampp x86 https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.2/ - You can check if you have x86 or x64 installed with `phpinfo()`

Comment: Thumbs up! Still works while updating to php 7.4 but you also need to do the exact same process for phpMyAdmin also because after upgrading it works but lots of deprecation notices come.

Comment: fails trying to upgrade 7.2 to php version 8.0

Comment: @shelbypereira what error you are getting btw I haven't tried yet upgrading PHP to 8.0 but I believe with little configuration the above steps should work

Comment: @VikasKhunteta hmm my setup may be more complicated becaus eI run Wordpress locally and was trying to upgrade to 8.0 php.  Errors were with calls to Mysql_Connect()  which are no longer supported in php 8.0.  there are other SO articles on how to solve this for wordpress.

Comment: Worked to update from php 7.4.7 to php 8.2.4. However, to restart apache without errors, I also needed to copy this file from the xampp source to existing installation: ```\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf```

Answer (score 65):

You can go through the following link as it helped me, should work for you as well. http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/07/updating-php-in-xampp-for-windows.html

Realizing that my answer helped couple of users, here is the edit from original link:

Edit:

## First of all Always backup your data.

1. Download the latest binary version of PHP (make sure to get the .zip package not the installer)
2. De-archive it to a directory
3. Overwrite the contents of directory in the php subfolder of your XAMPP installation directory.
4. Overwrite the contents of the directory  apache\bin with the newer versions.
5. **Now the trick**: take the files which have a '_2' in their names (for example php5apache2_2.dll or php5apache2_2_filter.dll), copy them in the apache\bin subdirectory and remove the '_2' part, overwriting the existing files. This is necessary because by XAMPP uses Apache version 2.2 and the files with the 2 prefix are built for Apache 2.0, so you must take the files build for the newer version (which has a different plugin interface) and rename them in the filenames XAMPP expects.

NOTE: there are two directories to be updated with new version of files, namely `php` sub-directory and `apache/bin` sub-directory, inside XAMPP installation.

Comment: Step 4 is not needed. After doing the rest I also copied the php.ini and php/extras from the backup folder. (It was also mentioned in the comments of the article, that helped me too)

Comment: @Dharmang: unfortunately i did shift+delete my all the xampp,php apache folder.... For trying to install latest version of php. Now i confused, how to start?.. can you help me please?

Comment: Now install the latest version, but your data (like www directory) is destroyed now, you can try some recovery software.

Comment: @Dharmang, thanks for your post. Can you tell me **where are the files you mentioned in STEP 5,** and also when do I need to replace them _before overwriting the content or after(as mentioned in STEP 3,4)_

Comment: You need to download the version of PHP you are interested from xampp site.

Answer (score 17):

I have upgraded to **php7.2** from **php5.6**

Steps which I followed.

1. Download PHP binary from [here](http://windows.php.net/download). I have downloaded **VC15 x86 Thread Safe Zip** file.
2. Created a backup of **xampp/php** folder.
3. Extract all the contents of zip file to xampp/php folder.
4. Copied **php.in**i (as I have modified it before and I want my configuration back, if you were using default one then skip this step.)
5. Edit below file

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\http-xampp.conf

5.1. Replace

> LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
>
> LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
>
> LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

to

> LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
>
> LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
>
> LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

6. Restart Apache

Comment: Not the perfect solution: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll ...

Comment: Try to download exact build. in my case it was VC15 x86 Thread Safe

Comment: @Harry - Please modify it to php7_mysql.dll (or whatever applicable). The question was to upgrade php module not other libraries.

Answer (score 14):

I needed to update my php from **5.3.8 to 5.3.29**. (both Thread Safe) on **Windows**

Steps I did:

1. Back-up my initial php folder, under xampp.
2. Downloaded zip from here
   http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.3-ts-VC9-x86
3. Unpack that zip into xampp folder.
4. Copied php.ini file from old php folder into new one.
5. Copied a couple of folders that I didn't have in the new php folder,
   from old one. For example: extras, which contained browscap.ini file
   (this one is needed)
6. Copied needed extensions, from old php **ext** folder into new php
   **ext** folder. I copied them manually, by checking list of extensions from php.ini file.
7. Copied also these files: php5apache2_2.dll, php5ts.dll

Hope that I covered everything.

Most probably these steps will not work if you change major versions of php, e.g. 5.3.x to 5.4.x, but for minor versions, it should work.

Also, a good way to see what's wrong... start command line and try to start httpd.exe, under xampp/apache/bin from there, it will list errors found.

Comment: Didn't work for going to php7, but from 5.5 to 5.6 worked well!

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to actually download and install XAMPP with the desired PHP version. I dont think you can just upgrade the components of XAMPP individually unless there is a facility provided for this within XAMPP itself.

Comment: XAMPP does not have the current PHP version, so a fresh install would be useless

Comment: You can upgrade the components of XAMPP, check my answer at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26483387/2733431)

Answer (score 9):

download your desired version of php binary from http://windows.php.net/download/ website. download  Thread Safe binary zip version.
Unzip the downloaded version of the PHP in a separate folder. 
Please make sure that your new php folder name is not "PHP". May be you can use filder name as the version name. For example for php 5.4 you can use php54.

Copy the new php folder into your xampp folder. Now go to yourxampp/apache/conf/extra folder. Open file httpd-xampp.conf from the folder extra. Change the following variables:

Variable PHPINIDir to be /
Varaible LoadModule to be //php5apache2_2.dl

Save the file httpd-xampp.conf. Restart your XAMPP apache server. If your server get restarted successfully then your server php version is upgraded.

Answer (score 5):

There are newer beta versions of Xampp that come with newer PHP upgrades.

you should check at http://www.apachefriends.org

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but, to add to ssharma's answer:

After you copy your htdocs folder to a safe place, just export your databases from PHPmyadmin. Simply go to each of your databases and click on the export tab at the top. Export them as sql (or whatever, really - just remember what you chose). Upgrade your XAMPP installation. Now, in the new version of XAMPP, create the databases that you want to re-insert. Example: you have a database named 'test' that you exported from your old installation, name the new, empty database the same thing. Now, go into 'test' and hit the import button along the top (right next to the export button). Click on choose file, find the sql file that you exported earlier (should be 'test.sql') and import. Your tables and data will be in place.

NOTE: There's an option to export the entire collection of databases (it names the file 127.0.0.1.sql). But, I've never had much luck getting it to import correctly. Do each of your databases separately to ensure it works. I made this post kind of long-winded, but that's because I like to write for the people that don't know exactly what they're doing yet (I, myself, was there not too long ago (all of us were at some point)).

Shorthand version of my answer:
1) Export your databases individually
2) Import into your new installation of XAMPP

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to `phpinfo()`, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, and type `thread` to check the value.
2. If it is enabled download the non thread safe version, otherwise download the thread safe version from [here](http://windows.php.net/download/) (zip).
3. Extract it, and rename the folder to `php`.
4. Go to your xampp folder rename the default `php` folder to something else.
5. Copy the extracted (renamed `php`) folder in xampp directory.
6. Copy the `php.ini` file from default/old `php` folder (That you renamed) and paste it into the new `php` folder.
7. Restart xampp server and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

I've updated the PHP to 8 by downloading the files from here.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/8.0.6/

Uploaded it to the xampp directory by renaming the previous PHP folder to something else. But, then got the following error while starting the apache.

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

After that, I've replaced the apache directory as well from the xampp folder with a newer version which I've downloaded, it sorted the issue out.

Got another problem while trying to access the phpmyadmin page, then again renamed the previous phpmyadmin folder from the xampp directory and uploaded the new version from the downloaded files. It's fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

In this site you can get

XAMPP Add-Ons

by using this add on you can upgrade the latest versions.

Comment: All the zipped folders/installation executable files I download from this link is either empty or corrupted! Please help?

Answer (score 3):

I just upgrade my old XAMPP portable with PHP 5.3.X(Include Mercury & FileZilla & Tomcat) to XAMPP portable with PHP 5.6.X ( Include previous versions ) ...
My way:

1. First download last xampp portable(my using version: xampp-portable-win32-5.6.14-3-VC11[Direct Download Link](http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.14/xampp-portable-win32-5.6.14-3-VC11.7z)) [Last XAMPP](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/)
2. Extract new download file to drive d , because new version dont have mercury,filezilla,tomcat in it , then i copy these packages from my old version to new one
3. Now on old xampp first copy all htdocs files to new xampp htdocs
4. Now on old xampp backup all of database in 5 two 10 separated sql files
5. Now on new xampp going and change some settings like `max_upload_size` and etc on php.ini and also in `/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`
6. Now delete ( make a rar archive and delete ) it , and copy new xampp from drive `D` to drive `C`
7. Now start new xampp , going to phpmyadmin , create a user and password that i use in previous xampp and add all privileges that user.
8. Now going to import tab on phpmyadmin and separately import sql files.
9. Now i test xampp with all new features in drive C

**NOTE**
On Export database tab on phpmyadmin, select UTF-8 Character and check `Disable foreign key checks` checkbox 
and on import tab uncheck `Enable foreign key checks`.

Answer (score 3):

1) Backup your htdocs folder 
2) export your databases  (follow [this](http://techsini.com/how-to-update-xampp-to-the-latest-version/) tutorial)

3) uninstall xampp

4) install the new version of xampp

5) replace the htdocs folder that you have backed  up

6) Import your databases you had exported before

**Note**: In case you have changed config files like PHP (php.ini), Apache (httpd.conf) or any other, please take back up of those files as well and replace them with newly installed version.

Answer (score 3):

To update with latest PHP version in xampp without losing your htdocs data you need to download the zip file of your desired version of PHP from sourceforge.net, then copy the PHP folder from the extracted file and paste it into your xampp folder.

NOTE: Don't forget to rename the old PHP file folder which already exists.

Then simply edit your php.ini file with the current path to reach the right PHP folder

After that, you need to re-run your xampp.

I found a video on youtube which can help you.
[how to update php version in xampp](https://youtu.be/U4zOtLOxh64)

Answer (score 2):

1) Download new PHP from the official site (better some zip). Old `php` directory rename to `php_old` and create again `php` directory and put there unzipped files.

In `php.ini` connect needed modules if you used something that was turned off by default (like Memcached etc.), but doesn't forget to add corresponding `.dll` files.

2) In my case, I had to update Apache. So repeat the same steps: download the new package, rename directories, create new `apache` directory and put their new files.

Now you can try to restart apache running `apache_start.bat` from `xampp` folder (better run this bat, than restart apache service from Windows services window, cause in this case in console you'll see all errors if there will be some, including lines in config where you'll have problem). If you updated Apache and run this file, in the list of services you'll see Apache2.2, but in description you can get another version (in my case that was Apache/2.4.7).

In case of Apache update you can get some problems, so mind:

- after you replace the whole directory, you may need to configure you `apache/conf/httpd.conf` file (copy virtual hosts from old config, set up DocumentRoots, permissions for directories, all paths, extend the list of index files (by default apache has only `index.html` so other index files will be just ignored and Apache will just list the site root directory in browser), configure you logs etc.)
- connect modules you need (if you used something that was not turned on by default like mod_rewrite etc.)

Answer (score 2):

### The ultimate guide to upgrading XAMPP and PHP

Note that it's **not recommended** to just swap out an older version of PHP in XAMPP to a newer version, as there's the possibility it could introduce problems and incompatibilities due to tools, configurations and codebases that weren't designed to play together.

**Instead, it's a much safer idea** to update the PHP version with the rest of XAMPP - this will upgrade both PHP and any other binaries that PHP needs to work with, including MySQL and PHPMyAdmin, to versions that are designed to be compatible with it. This way you will also be able to take advantage of the security and speed advantages of updating to newer versions - for example, modern versions of PHPMyAdmin are miles faster and much less buggy than versions that are a few years old.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to update XAMPP, which is bizarre considering how old and mature it is as a project, but the good news is it can be easily accomplished using the steps below.

---

### How to properly update XAMPP and PHP 8.x

1. Rename your current, working `XAMPP` folder (located at `C:\xampp` by default) to `XAMPP.old` or something similar to indicate it's the old version.
2. [Download the XAMPP installer](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for the version of XAMPP/PHP you want (*the XAMPP version mirrors the PHP version to make it easier to know which PHP version you're getting*), and install it to `C:\xampp`.
3. Go through the install process and feel free to deselect any software you don't need - like Mercury Mail and Tomcat - to prevent them cluttering up your installation, then wait for the install to complete.
4. Delete the following folders from `C:\xampp` and copy and paste their equivalents from `C:\xampp.old`:

   ```
   htdocs
   mysql\data
   mysql\backup
   ```

You've now moved all of your website and database data over from your last installation, so if you didn't customise your XAMPP configuration a lot or don't care about moving your configuration over, you can stop at this stage and you will have a fully-working installation of XAMPP running on your new version of PHP, along with new software that is compatible with it.

---

Next, you need to copy over the configuration files from your old XAMPP installation at `C:\xampp.old` to the new one at `C:\xampp`.

First is the `php\php.ini` file - this file should **not** simply be copied over, as it contains configuration options that are very specific to the current PHP installation.  If you've made changes to it or you're not sure whether you have, you can use a diff tool like `diff --color -y <old php.ini> <new php.ini>` to compare your old `php.ini` file with the one you just installed - if you see any lines in **red**, these are the lines you might need to copy over to your new `C:\xampp\php.ini` file, although note that even many of these might be unnecessary - usually they are removed by the developers because they're no longer needed by the newer PHP version.

The remaining configuration files and folders can simply be copied below into the same locations on `C:\xampp`, replacing the newer versions:

```
apache\conf\httpd.conf
apache\conf\ssl.crt
apache\conf\ssl.csr
apache\conf\ssl.key
phpmyadmin\config.inc.php
apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

All of these changes should be pretty safe but it's always a good idea to keep the `C:\xampp.old` folder around for a few weeks while you're testing out your new XAMPP server. If it turns out you missed something you can then just copy it over later.

You should now be able to open the XAMPP Control Panel to start the server and confirm that your new versions of Apache and MySQL are working, and visit `localhost/phpmyadmin` to confirm that the latest version of PHPMyAdmin has been installed successfully. Finally, run `php -v` to confirm that you're on the installed version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

In order to run apache server after upgradation PHP 7.4.x requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 which can be downloaded [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019) under the heading [Other Tools and Frameworks](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other-family). otherwise apache server won't start.

Answer (score 0):

For Upgradation php in Xampp you can follow this steps, Else you can skip these 4 steps and direct install MAMP (for windows as well) from [site](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) and here is the [direct download link](http://downloads6.mamp.info/MAMP-PRO-WINDOWS/releases/3.3.0/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_3.3.0.exe)

**Step 1:** Make backups
Before starting, make sure to backup any settings, custom modules and most importantly the htdocs directory, which contains your scripts and page resources. This directory is normally located atC:\xampp\htdocs\

**Step 2:** Preparation

Download PHP 5.3.0rc2. I use the VC6 build in order to minimise any potential compatibility issues.
    It is also recommended that you download the latest Windows version of XAMPP. While this is an upgrade guide that shouldwork with previous versions of XAMPP, it is recommended that a fresh copy of the core files is used.
    Stop any instances of the Apache service that might be running.

**Step 3:** The upgrade
This guide will assume your XAMPP directory is C:\xampp\

Extract the XAMPP archive to a directory of your choosing, I would recommend using the default C:\xampp\
    Extract the contents of the PHP archive to C:\xampp\php\, overwriting the contents of this directory with the new files.
    Open the file C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf and ensure the following lines are present in this order:

```
LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/apache/bin/php5apache2_2.dll"

Replace C:\xampp\php\php.ini with C:\xampp\php\php.ini-dist
Uncomment the lines:

;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

Replace the line

magic_quotes_gpc = On

with

magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

> Copy all files in the C:\xampp\php\ to C:\xampp\apache\bin\ (do not
>   copy the subdirectories or their contents).

After following the above steps, restart your Apache service (this can be done using C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe or manually through the control panel/command prompt). Your PHPinfo should indicate that the upgrade has been successful.
I will update this post if I discover any problems from using this method, or a cleaner (automated) means of performing the upgrade.