# Upgrade current XAMPP 1.6.8 with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, xampp

I'm running XAMPP 1.6.8 on Windows 7 Ultimate and I wonder how can I upgrade my current installation with PHP 5.3.x without changing the whole XAMPP.

Can I just download PHP 5.3 from php.net and replace the PHP folder inside XAMPP?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant. php_mod is what XAMPP uses, unless you can get XAMPP to use ISAPI, or CGI. ISAPI is supposed to be called inside of apache, CGI is supposed to run on request, FastCGI is supposed to be better than both.

But assuming your using XAMPP you'll only want to use the version that works best for Windows 7. More likely plain PHP CGI will be updated the most often since its a generic library from PHP not dependant on what web server software you use.