# How can I update my version of PHP for XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)

I am currently using XAMPP version 1.8.1 which has the PHPversion 5.4.3

I have found the latest version of PHP from the PHP site version 5.4.11, released a day ago.

Now if I download the latest PHP version from php.net and replace my current PHP directory with the latest, will it work properly/ straight away?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Download the latest binary version of [PHP 5.4.11](http://windows.php.net/download/) (make sure to get the .zip package not the installer)
- De-archive it to a directory
- Copy the contents of the directory in the php subfolder of your XAMPP installation directory, overwriting the files which are already present
- Overwrite the files which are already present in the apache\bin directory with the newer versions.
- **Now the trick:** take the files which have a "_2" in their names (for example php5apache2_2.dll or php5apache2_2_filter.dll), copy them in the apache\bin subdirectory and remove the "_2" part, overwriting the existing files. This is necessary because by XAMPP uses Apache version 2.2 and the files with the 2 prefix are built for Apache 2.0, so you must take the files build for the newer version (which has a different plugin interface) and rename them in the filenames XAMPP expects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this step is not working in my xampp.. i tried to update my php 5.2 to 5.6 and its not working apache is not starting