# How do I update xampp on windows to the php 5.5 beta?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm developing on a windows computer and using xampp. I want to use php 5.5 because it has a new simplified password hashing API. It says here: http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-04-11-1 that the beta3 version of php 5.5 is available.

I've looked through similar stackoverflow questions, and found this:
http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/07/updating-php-in-xampp-for-windows.html

I feel like this is what I need, except I'm confused about where to find the newer versions of the files in the apache\bin directory. Is that somewhere in the downloaded php 5.5 files?

Comment: I would ask that in the xampp community forums instead. People over there might know better, e.g. which compiler needs  to be use and so on to have it compatible with the apache compile they ship with.

Comment: http://windows.php.net/qa/ gives you the 5.5.0-beta3 binaries, but you won't find a full set of extensions available yet

Comment: Here's the answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412379/how-can-i-update-my-version-of-php-for-xampp