# Trying to Create a function on a namespaced class with 'resource' type

Tags: php, class, types, namespaces, resources

Good Morning @everybody, I am trying to Create a function on a namespaced class which returns a 'resource' type, however, I am failing to do it.

What I tried to do:#1

```
public function SQLQuery($query):resource
{
    // the magic...
}
```

to be used with the folllowing syntax:

```
$SQL = SQLQuery('SELECT * FROM my_db');
```

but it resulted in:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' because i'm running PHP 5.6 
>   and that feature requires PHP 7...

so i have tried another method but it didn't work with me too:#2

```
public function SQLQuery($query, &$resrc)
{
    $resrc = mysqli_query($SQLDB, $query);
    // the magic...
}

SQLQuery('SELECT * FROM my_db', $resrc_var);
```

so i have tried another method which worked for me at least basiclly:#3

```
public function SQLQuery($query)
{
    $resrc = mysqli_query($SQLDB, $query);
    // the magic...
    return $resrc;
}

$SQL = SQLQuery('SELECT * FROM my_db');
```

Comment: I don't get the error that you are saying it returns. Are you sure that error is for that snippet?

Comment: The error I get is: `Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Test::SQLQuery() must be an instance of resource, none returned in /run_dir/repl.php(68) : eval()'d code:5
Stack trace:
#0 /run_dir/repl.php(68) : eval()'d code(8): Test->SQLQuery('test')
#1 /run_dir/repl.php(68): eval()
#2 {main}
  thrown`

Comment: @Script47 yes, iam sure (XAMPP's PHP 5.6)

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652231/trying-to-create-a-function-on-a-namespaced-class-with-resource-type/50652345#comment88315398_50652231), you are using PHP [5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php), however [return types](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) were introduced in PHP 7+. Therefore, to use that feature, you will need to update to PHP 7 or higher.

Comment: so that feature must be used on php 7 or later ??

Comment: Iam going to upgrade my systems to PHP 7.2.6... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296466/upgrading-xampp-to-run-php-7

Comment: @JohnSpanish yes, you need to update to PHP 7 or higher.