# PHP 7: Missing VCRUNTIME140.dll

Tags: php, windows, dll, php-7

I have an error when I start PHP 7 on Windows. When I run `php` on the command line, it returns a message box with system error:

> The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After that, `CLI` is crashing.

As I don't want to install a DLL file from an external website, I don't know how to fix this!

**PHP version:** [7.0.0alpha1 VC14 x64 Thread Safe](http://windows.php.net/downloads/qa/php-7.0.0alpha1-Win32-VC14-x64.zip)

Comment: Nominating for reopen on this basis: "they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". Which is true of this question.

Comment: even same problem with me mine is VC6 x84 but unable to install wampserver. i have searched all over google . Kindly help me .

Comment: @Pavan Baddi - I had troubles too with certain VC versions not working with my WAMP. Installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 x64 and x86 (run with admin privileges) alongside Wampserver x64 3.0.6 and it works now.

Comment: The solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482393/vcruntime140-dll-missing fix it for me

Answer (score 234, accepted):

On the *side bar* of the [PHP 7 alpha download page](http://windows.php.net/qa/), it does say this:

> VC9, VC11 & VC14
>   More recent versions of PHP are built with VC9, VC11
>   or VC14 (Visual Studio 2008, 2012 or 2015 compiler respectively) and
>   include improvements in performance and stability.
>
> - The VC9 builds require you to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) or [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) installed
> - The VC11 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 [x86 or x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed
> - The VC14 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 [x86 or x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) installed

<sup>There's been a problem with some of those links, so the files are also available from [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Microsoft-Visual-C-Redistributable-Package.shtml#download).</sup>

In the case of the PHP 7 alpha, it's the last option that's required.

I think that the placement of this information is poor, as it's kind of marginalized (i.e.: it's basically literally in the margin!) whereas it's actually critical for the software to run.

I documented my experiences of getting PHP 7 alpha up and running on Windows 8.1 in [PHP: getting PHP7 alpha running on Windows 8.1](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/06/php-getting-php7-alpha-running-on.html), and it covers some more symptoms that might crop up. They're out of scope for this question but might help other people.

Other symptom of this issue:

- Apache not starting, claiming `php7apache2_4.dll` is missing despite it definitely being in place, and offering nothing else in any log.
- `php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly` (as per @ftexperts's comment below)

Attempted solution:

- Using the `php7apache2_4.dll` file from an earlier PHP 7 dev build. *This did not work.*

(I include those for googleability.)

Comment: Another symptom in IIS7:
"php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly"

Comment: None of the microsoft.com download links work for me (gateway timeout error). Alternative mirrors are here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Microsoft-Visual-C-Redistributable-Package.shtml#download

Comment: @rybo111I think it was transient or problem on your end? They're OK for me (didn't check all of them). But I reckon I'll add your link as an alternative to the answer though! Cheers.

Comment: I install almost every version but getting the same error VCRUNTIME140.dll when I install  version of 2015  Update RC 2
.dll error get away , may help someone else

Comment: The dam **sidebar** with all the important information is one of the most powerful examples of usability fails I've ever seen.

Comment: I have installed VC 2015, update 1, update 2 and this didn't solve the problem. Still having 'VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing' error.

Comment: Not with PHP 7 but with some other VC runtime-using app I had... I had a conflict between one of my already-existing runtimes and the one the app was supposed to be looking for. I cannot remember the details but I needed to deinstall some existing ones and reinstall just the more recent ones. It's not something I need to look at very often, sorry to sound vague.

Comment: current download link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Comment: Installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows Server and PHP works fine as f now! Thank you! <3

Comment: i fould the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59414266/14629458)

Answer (score 25):

*[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)* (x32 bit version) - RC.

This should correct that. You can google for what the DLL *is*, but that's not important.

PS: It's officially from Microsoft too:)

Where I found it: *[Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs)* (Visual Studio)

Comment: I google the DLL but I didn't find one. I will try this pack.

Comment: Possible better link for both 32- and 64-bit distros: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46881

Answer (score 18):

Installing **[vc_redist.x86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)** works for me even though you have a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I use the 32bit of vc_redist.x86.exe edition even though I have 64 platform (win10)

Answer (score 14):

If you've followed Adam's instructions and you're *still* getting this error make sure you've installed the right variants (x86 or x64).

I had VC14x64 with PHP7x86 and I still got this error. Changing PHP7 to x64 fixed it. It's easy to miss you accidentally installed the wrong version.

Answer (score 11):

For things like this, you don't blindly keep clicking '*Next*', '*Next*', and '*I Agree*'.

WAMP informs you about this during and before installation:

> The MSVC runtime libraries VC9, VC10, VC11 are required for Wampserver
>   2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions with VC11. Runtimes VC13, VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17
>
> VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
>
> VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
>
> VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4) The two files
>   VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on
>   the same page:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>
> VC13 Packages] (Visual C++ 2013[) The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe
>   and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
>
> VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015) The two files vcredist_x86.exe and
>   vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145
>
> **You must install both 32 and 64bit versions**, even if you do not use
>   Wampserver 64 bit.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Be sure to to run all Microsoft Visual C++ installations with administrator privileges (right click → *Run as Administrator*). Just missing this small step wasted my entire day.

Comment: I can't edit your post but for wamp users, can refer to this http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ There is a check tool to validate if all VC packages are installed. Additional to the packages mentioned by @user3284463, must be installed Visual C++ 2008 SP1 ATL Security Update Redist. Package and Visual C++ 2008 SP1 MFC Security Update Redist. Package. All information needed is in the link above.

Answer (score 3):

I  had same problem when installing Robot Framework 2.9.2 using the Windows installer version on Windows 7.

I could solve it installing the VC14 builds require to have the "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86 or x64 installed" from [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Answer (score 1):

I got same error and found that *my* Microsoft Visual C++ is 32 bit and Windows is 64 bit. I tried to install WAMP 7 32 bit and the problem was solved.

Maybe we need to install WAMP 32 bit if Visual Studio is 32 bit. And vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I changed the ports, restarted the services but in vein,  only worked for me when I updated the Microsoft Visual c++ files[image: From There yoy can modify MVC]

Answer (score -4):

Usually this is an error in your PHP configuration.

It's actually pretty easy to figure out what exactly is going on:

- Create a small file (test.php) with the standard phpinfo() script
- Open a command prompt
- Start php manually using the small file, e.g. '"\program files\php\php.exe" test.php
- Read the error messages :-)