# installing apache: no VCRUNTIME140.dll

Tags: apache

My OS is Windows 7,x64.

I've downloaded files from the official server (Apache2.4), but my attempt to install it failed:
 `httpd -k install` ,typed in command prompt (it was opened by administrator) given a "no VCRUNTIME140.dll" error.

But i have Microsoft Visual C++ both x64 and x86 installed. What's the problem??

Comment: Got it. THe answer is here - http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=30853. "Quote from the download page: "Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC : VC14 vcredist_x64/86.exe""

Comment: Please look on this link, Hope it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811668/php-7-missing-vcruntime140-dll

Answer (score 71):

Be sure you have C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC. Try to download the last version:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Obs: Credit to [parsecer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759176/parsecer)

Comment: Does the pc requires a restart?

Comment: @giannischristofakis yes

Comment: This works and yes, the restart was necessary. I misread the answer and installed x64.exe, assuming .x86.exe didn't apply to me however it was indeed the missing culprit.

Comment: its not working even after installing and restarting the system

Comment: You've stolen my answer(

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. and didn't even need to restart my pc!

Comment: Didn't need a restart either.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, my issue was that downloaded Apache 2.4 but 32 bits. Then re-download 64bits version and it's works.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Downloading 32bit application on a 64bit computer will not break anything, it just means memory is being wasted when the application is in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Also, please make sure you installed the correct version of apache on your computer. For example, not install a x86 on a 64bit system. Vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I was gone through same problem & I resolved it by following steps.

1. Uninstall earlier version of wamp server, which you are trying to install.
2. Install which ever file supports to your configuration (64, 86) from en [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
3. Restart your computer.
4. Install wampserver now.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your OS is Windows 7 Service Pack 1.. use 
"winver" to verify.

[image: Make sure Service Pack 1 is there after "Build #### : Service Pack 1"]

Comment: Brake it down to the important parts instead of linking to another page.

Answer (score -2):

Problem: Wamp Won't Turn Green & VCRUNTIME140.dll error

Solved:)

You need C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC. Try to download  the file, vc_redist.x64.exe from here, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

**if you already installed then uninstalled it first**

1. I installed the vc_redist.x64.exe (if you OS is 32 bit then you should download  vc_redist.x86.exe)
2. then installed the wampserver (if you already installed then unsintalled it first)

Comment: Stop repeating answers.