# Apache won't start in uniServer

Tags: html, apache

When trying to 'Start Apache' in **UniServer** I am being faced with the error message:

> "The programme cant start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing on your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Anyone have any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493605/installing-apache-no-vcruntime140-dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 [x86 or x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).