# Can't able to run/start apache in XAMPP control panel v3.2.4

Tags: php

I couldn't able to "start apache" in XAMPP control panel v3.2.4 in my laptop ie; on Windows 7 .

IT SAYS "the program can't start because VCRTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".

Error:Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 
This may be due to a blocked port ,missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash,or a shutdown by another method.Press the button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues if you need more help,and post this entire log window on the forums.

Comment: Try to Reinstall xamp

Answer (score 1):

Do you have C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC?

Check this question: [installing apache: no VCRUNTIME140.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493605/installing-apache-no-vcruntime140-dll)

Comment: I don't have c++ redistributable for visual studio 2015 Rc what should I do now ? And for what purpose it is used?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685 . Check the details.  **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable installs run-time components of Visual C++ libraries. These components are required to run C++ applications that are developed using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 RC and link dynamically to Visual C++ libraries.**. Also check the version of your system and xampp (x86 or x64)

Comment: I have downloaded Ms visual c++ 2015 redistributable but also the same issue.  I'm trying again & again  but it showing the same result as before.

Comment: @user12351761 Are you using the same version of Visual C++ as  your system version? Or you can do install **vcredist_x64/86.exe** version. Anyway, after installing ** Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 **, try to reinstall your xampp.

Comment: Did it help? Is your XAMPP working now? if so, set the answer as the best to close the question. Thanks!

Comment: Now I wanna uninstall xampp permanently how i should uninstall?