# VCRUNTIME140.dll missing

Tags: windows, apache, dll

I have a problem when trying to install apache 2.4 on my windows 10. It always shows the error that VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing. I have checked other threads and found out that installing the 2015 Visual c++ Redistributables x64/x86 always solves the problem but I have both installed and I still have this problem. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Did you restart after installation? Restart is required. Did you install BOTH the x64 and x86? Link to the "other threads" you've referenced.

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Comment: possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811668

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue after installing wamp on windows 10.This worked for me.

- Download [VCRUNTIME140.DLL](http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=vcruntime140.dll&arch=64bit&version=14.0.22816.0&dsc=)
- Copy the dll file to `C:\Windows\System32` using administrative privileges.
- Try reinstalling apache.

Answer (score 14):

You need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC, please find the link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685), choose between the 32bit or the 64bit.

Reinstall the apache 2.4 and error should gone.

Answer (score 7):

Download and install the proper version of `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC` regarding your hardware architecture (x86 / x64). Use the link below:
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 6 X64, got an error 500 on any PHP files, 
installing the 2015 Visual c++ Redistributables x64 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'v already had VC 2015 Redist on my PC but files were not copied into `Windows\System32`.

So I copied missing files directly to this folder. A thing that I should mention is since I compiled my application in `X86` mode I copied them from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86

not

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64

I know that this solution is not the ideal one, but it was a workaround for my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Visual C/C++ and you have already downloaded VCRUNTIME140.DLL, Go to Project Properties->Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Code Generation, Set Runtime Library Multi-threaded (/MT)

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove apache 2.4 from your pc
2. Download VCRUNTIME140.dll from this [link](http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=vcruntime140.dll&arch=64Bit&version=14.0.22816.0&dsc=Microsoft%AE-C-Runtime-Library#)
3. Copy VCRUNTIME140.dll file and paste it inside to Windows/System32
4. Finally reinstall apache and run

Comment: Do not play with DLLs this way, it is potentially dangerous for system stability. Putting a DLL in Windows/system32 will affect ALL installed applications. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell