# Issue when running an exe file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll

Whenever I try running an exe file in Visual Studio 2010 I get the error message: the program can't run because vcruntime140.dll is missing from your computer. And the same message for ucrtbased.dll. I downloaded both of the dlls, but I dont know where to place them within the system files so that this would be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VCRUNTIME140.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482393/vcruntime140-dll-missing)

Comment: You are using a library that can only work with a VS2015 install.  You'll have to rebuild it.  Or ask the owner to provide you with one that is suitable for VS2010.  Or update VS.