# An error is reported when the java -verison command is executed in winpowershell

Tags: java, windows, java-8

When I installed the jdk and executed the java-version command, the error was reported as follows
[image]

I want to install the springboot project on winserver2008 and report an error after installing jdk.
The system version is `Windows server2008 R2 Enterprise` and my jdk version is `1.8.0_261`.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482393/vcruntime140-dll-missing) answers your question.

Comment: There are a number of possible fixes for "missing vcruntime140.dll" problems at https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/vcruntime140-dll-not-found-error-fixed/

Comment: I can't be more specific ... 'cos I don't run Windows.  ^^^ is something that Googling found for me.  I should also add that Windows Server 2008 is 2 years beyond its "end of life"; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/extended-security-updates-deploy

Comment: The system belongs to a partner company, I cannot upgrade this system!

Comment: But you could tell your contacts at the partner company that they >should< upgrade ... and warn them that you will not be held responsible for problems caused by their running an EOL operating system.  (At some point they will be burned.)

Comment: And when you think about it ... you are already being impacted by this because you are having to spend extra effort to get you software to run on their out-of-date system.  (I hope that they are paying for the extra work you have to do ...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will follow your suggestion to communicate this