# Visual Studio 2022 - "VCRUNTIME140.dll Is Missing"

Tags: visual-studio, parallels, macos-monterey, windows-11

I've tried a half dozen things, but I cannot get Visual Studio working. I keep getting this error when trying to build/debug any program, no matter how simple.

Any suggestions? Here's what I've tried:

- Reset and completely reinstalled Windows 11 (new VM)
- Reset and completely reinstalled Visual Studio 2022
- Installed latest Visual C++ Redistributable (x64 & ARM)
- Storing the project on the shared MacOS/Windows drive
- Storing the project directly on the Windows drive (virtual)
- Verifying that the DLL is in fact stored in System32 (it was)

This is a 21H2 Windows 11 ARM Virtual Machine running via Parallels on MacOS Monterey 12.1.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAAd0.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4njpq.png)

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0M8g.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VCRUNTIME140.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482393/vcruntime140-dll-missing). Ignore the accepted answer, as it's wrong. See the other answers.

Comment: @KenWhite https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168045/17937389 This response specifically was the answer. I would have never looked there, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. When you've earned enough reputation here to get the voting privilege, please remember to go back and upvote that answer to thank the user who wrote it. :-)