# .dll file missing after php upgrade

Tags: php, dll, windows-8, xampp

I upgraded my PHP version of XAMPP from 5.2 to 7 following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480590/upgrade-php-on-xampp-1-8-3-windows-7-installation) post. But I am getting an error while I run **php -v** command. Can anyone say what is the solution??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dll-files.com/php5ts.dll.html

Dowload this dll file and copy that all dll file in your computer dll file folder.