# How can I upgrade PHP version from 5.4 to 5.6 on xampp windows?

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp with php version 5.4 and I want to upgrade the php version to 5.6, how can I do that without reinstall the xampp?

Thanks

Comment: @DevMaillano You must do your home work before putting any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is copy your phpmyadmin and htdocs folder from xampp and then reinstall latest version of xampp.

[Reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)