# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused after update XAMPP with PHP 7.2 on mac

Tags: laravel, xampp, database-migration

Everything worked fine until I update XAMPP with PHP from 7.1 to 7.2. I noticed to access phpmyadmin using this new XAMPP on mac, need port 8080 (http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin). Is this the problem? I already tried to change DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost but nothing works.

Here my .env looks like

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Comment: localhost is a DNS for 127.0.0.1 so it does not matter if you write the DNS or write the IP and the default port is 8080 so again it does not matter if you write it or not. please give us more info

Comment: remove quotes from DB_PASSWORD='' just simply DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: What version Laravel are you using? This answer might be helpful in migration to a newer version of PHP on Windows/XAMPP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: I'm using XAMPP-VM (PHP 7.2.4). I already tried using DB_PASSWORD= , but still received same error

Comment: could you fix this?

Comment: No. I decided to downgrade the XAMPP version