# XAMPP Can't Start Apache After Upgrading to PHP7.1.17 "Attempting to start Apache service..."

Tags: apache, xampp, php-7.1

I have XAMPP installed on Windows 7 virtual machine. My old PHP version was 7.0.9 with Apache 2.4

I needed to upgrade the PHP version to 7.1.x and I set out reading about how to best to this. In end, I settled with the simple plan:

1. Stop Apache service
2. Downloaded new PHP version from official php website. For PHP 7 the 7.1.17 version was listed. I downloaded the thread safe version, as my Apache has thread safety enabled.
3. I extracted the contents of the downloaded archive to a folder.
4. I copied and replaced all files in the appropriate folders from C:/Server/php with the new php version files from the extracted archive.
5. I attempted to start Apache from the XAMPP control panel and the server will not start.

The message "Attempting to start Apache service..." just hangs and nothing happens.

The last entry in the error.log file in C:\Server\apache\logs shows the event when the server was stopped and that's it.

When I check the php version from CLI with the command php -v, the console returns installed php version 7.1.17

I tried different suggestions I read from similar questions, like changing ServerName localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:8080 and copying php7apache2.dll to apache/bin ( as suggested here: [Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows) ), alas the issue is not fixed and Apache does not start.

Of course, I also restarted the virtual machine, all the same.

At this point, I'm dumbfounded. Don't know what to do.

I need to get Apache running with php 7.1, as it is required by Magento 2.2.4. I do not want to reinstall XAMPP, as this will be a lenghty process with a lot of risk for more things to go wrong.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Alright, so after checking Windows Logs > Application in Event Viewer I saw the error ".. the Apache service named is not a valid win32 application". I downloaded the x86 version of PHP from official website [PHP for Windows](https://windows.php.net/download)

Then copied and replaced files as described above, and Apache started successfully.

To see if your Apache version is x64 or x86 open command prompt and cd to your Apache bin directory, in my case C:/Server/apache/bin , then run:

```
file httpd
```

Comment: I wasn't able to run `file httpd` to verify, but indeed it seems that I needed the x86 version EVEN THOUGH my Windows is 64-bit. After that, it worked like a charm!