# How to integrate Paypal payment gateway in Laravel ? (i got the errors)

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment, php-7

I am getting the errors but I have upgraded my PHP version already but still I am getting the same.

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector (locked at v1.3.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
```

Comment: Just compare `php -v` result and `<?php phpinfo() ?>` result, you may find more info. looks like your php under command line (Comes from path variables) and server versions are different(Specified under web server conf).

Answer (score 0):

This package([doctrine/inflector](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/inflector)) requires **php: ^7.1** and your PHP version (7.0.33), so that's why you got an error,

Update your php version, For used Upgrading your PHP in XAMPP for Windows: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: PHP 7.2.15 (cli) (built: Feb 26 2019 16:24:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

I have upgraded the php version but still i am getting that error

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of downgrade laravel to version 5.5 in a composer.json file (the easiest way) or upgrade your php to version 7.1.3 or later

Comment: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.


its giving me this error

Comment: It looks like your missing credentials in your request. PayPal returns pretty informative errors. Pls, follow developer documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ or documentation of the library you use