# I can't install Jetstream: [InvalidArgumentException]Package laravel/jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I can't install Jetstream to my Laravel project. When I use the command `composer require laravel / jetstream`, it will generate the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The laravel / jetstream package has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP 
extensions and
Composer version
```

My PHP version is `7.2.24`, and my Composer version is `2.0.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Jetstream requires PHP version to be minimum **7.3** so you need to upgrade your PHP version to a minimum of 7.3. It would be better if you upgrade it to PHP 7.4 at least. As PHP 7.3 is now EOL - meaning no active support for PHP 7.3, only security fixes for one more year.

https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Laravel Jetstream also requires **ext-json** to be enabled for PHP. So depending upon your PHP version i.e. 7.3.x or 7.4.x or 8.x you need to install ext-json as well - `php7.3-json` or `php7.4-json` or `php8.0-json`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem I just upgraded the version of my PHP 7.3 or above and you should also have laravel version 8 to use jetstream. So for upgrading the PHP version in xampp you can refer to this question.

[Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)