# Upgrade PHP 7.1.0 to 7.4.X on windows fail

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, magento2

hope you are developers are doing fine.

I am front end developer to install Magento 2 I tried to upgrade my ver 7.1 to 7.4 in xampp downloaded the latest version from **https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0** all setup done as per steps problem is I am not able to find file php.ini in the latest version I am getting error while running localhost/phpmyadmin
[image]
Using xampp version 3[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: did you overwrite your old installation folder? try to search for other php.ini files in your dowloaded code

Comment: I don't think you should be mixing Xampp and official binaries. You'd better stick to one of them.

Comment: If you're using XAMPP, then upgrade XAMPP to a version with 7.4 instead of manually installing a new PHP version (that XAMPP won't know exists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading PHP in XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: As an aside - Magento doesn't officially support Windows; there was a weird (read really stupid) bug in the way it built filesystem paths that broke on Windows machines - you'd probably be better off setting up a *nix Virtualbox or Vagrant package.

Comment: @Reynier yes i tried search it was not available in new downloaded php 7.4 version

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for your advice

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is it possible to upgrade XAMPP without disturbing my current working projects ???

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "disturbing". You will have down time while installing it (since XAMPP is a development environment, not a production environment). But other than that, if you follow the answer in the link I posted you should probably be OK (not using XAMPP myself so can't confirm it). Just make sure to read the comments for that answer as well to see if there can be other things you need to think about.