# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Locale" not found

Tags: php, xampp

I was making a project called blogpanel, and my xampp file is in localdisk:D.
I want to use vs code terminal to execute commands, but it shows me error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Locale" not found in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\blogpanel\system\I18n\TimeTrait.php:74

I googled and also enabled the extension=intl in my php.ini file, after restarting server, device. it still shows me the same error. Please provide the detailed solution for this.

Comment: Did you changed the right php.ini ? Run `phpinfo()` (in a web page, not CLI because it may use another config) to check the path to the file that is used by your XAMPP installation.

Comment: Can you share more details? How is this problem related to [tag:local-class]?

Comment: The [Locale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) class in indeed provided by the **intl** extension. While you certainly edited some INI file, you haven't really enabled the extension. Did you edit the correct file? Do you see the extension in `phpinfo()`? Is your system configured to display startup errors?

Comment: I have uncommented the intl extension that is in Apache/Config/php.ini file, but it still shows me error .
Uncaught Error: Class "Locale" not found in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\blogpanel\system\I18n\TimeTrait.php:74

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated the PHP version to PHP 7.4+ on XAMPP correctly
like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why shouldn't this work in earlier versions of PHP?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35397563)

Comment: It should be a comment.

Comment: @NicoHaase if you use CI as a framework, you can read about it in their documentation.

Comment: Yes, I should comment, but my account doesn't do that

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Can you post a link to the documentation you refer to? CI should also be compatible with older versions of PHP, and `Locale` is a class that intl provides since PHP 5.3

Comment: @NicoHaase https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html#optional-php-extensions

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer**, and share context. That version constraint only applies for CI 4.2.0 or later - are you sure the OP is using that version?